# Joda DateTime,, Formatting, and Mysql Timestamp

Tags: java, datetime

After a week of going through so many examples, and moving from Java Date,
to Calendar, to Joda. I have decided to seek help from other sources.

The problem:

Our table has two fields Date (Timestamp), and TZ (String). The idea is to store
the user's UTC in timestamp, and timezone, well, you get the idea. So basically
we think in UTC, and present the user with the time converted to their
timezone on the front end (ie, using the value store in table.TZ)

Another requirement is to use the proper Object (Date, DateTime whatever).
And not pass a String representation of the date around. The best would
be a valid Long that will be correctly translated by MySQL, without having
to use the FROM_UNIXTIME mysql function in our query.

Code we are using:

```
public DateTime convertTimezone(LocalDateTime date, DateTimeZone srcTZ, DateTimeZone dstTZ, Locale l) {
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss").withLocale(l);

DateTime srcDateTime = date.toDateTime(srcTZ);
DateTime dstDateTime = srcDateTime.toDateTime(dstTZ);

System.out.println(formatter.print(dstDateTime));
System.out.println(formatter.parseDateTime(dstDateTime.toString()));


return formatter.parseDateTime(formatter.print(dstDateTime));
}
```

The String output is exactly what we need (ie UTC time, 2013-08-23 18:19:12),
but the `formatter.parseDateTime(dstDateTime.toString()` is crashing with the following
error. Probably because of the UTC timezone independent info, and milleseconds?:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid format: "2013-08-    23T18:19:12.515Z" is malformed at "T18:19:12.515Z"
at org.joda.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.parseDateTime(DateTimeFormatter.java:873)
at com.example.business.rate.RateDeck.convertTimezone(RateDeck.java:75)
at com.example.business.rate.RateDeck.WriteData(RateDeck.java:143)
at com.example.business.rate.RateDeck.main(RateDeck.java:64)
```

Search engine enriched question:

How to format UTC for Joda DateTime.

PS My first SO post, and it feels nice? :)

Thanks in Advance,

The new fixed version:

```
public Timestamp convertTimezone(LocalDateTime date, DateTimeZone srcTZ, DateTimeZone dstTZ, Locale l) {
DateTime srcDateTime = date.toDateTime(srcTZ);
DateTime dstDateTime = srcDateTime.toDateTime(dstTZ);
return new Timestamp(dstDateTime.getMillis());
}
```

Nick.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's simply crashing because the format of the parsed string doesn't match with the format of the formatter.

The formatter parses using the format `yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss`, and the `toString()` method of `DateTime` formats the date it using ([as documented](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/base/AbstractInstant.html#toString%28%29)) the ISO8601 format (yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.SSSZZ).

Comment: Thanks but isn't the formatter in charge of reshaping the representation regardless? I'm not sure I follow :S. I see what you are saying, changing the formatter to "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZZ", stops the crashing and outputs the correct UTC "2013-08-23T21:28:04.290+00:00" however, we need the DateTime format to be in "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss".

Comment: The formatter formats a DateTime as a String when you ask it to do so, using `formatter.prin(theDateTimeToFormat)`. But you don't. You call `DateTime.toString()` to transform the DateTime into a String. I don't really understand what you want to do with thsoe System.out.println statements BTW.

Comment: A DateTime doesn't have any format. It's a number of milliseconds, and a timezone identifier. Only that. When you transform this value to a String, then you can choose which format to use, thanks to a DateTimeFormatter. The toString() method transforms the DateTime into a String using the ISO8601 format.

Comment: Understood. Is there a function that represents the DateTime in a `Long` or `DateTime` object that plays nice with MySQL? My problem  is that Mysql is complaining about "Data truncation: Incorrect datetime value: '2013-08-23T17:28:04.322-04:00'". Without converting it to String which I already works nicely.

Comment: Oh I missed that part, the System.out statements is just to make sure I am able to format DateTime in a way that will allow the value to be stored in the database.Just for testing...

Comment: To insert a DateTime into MySQL, just do `new java.sql.Timestamp(dateTime.toMillis())`, and insert this timestamp using a PreparedStatement. Don't use Strings to insert Dates.

Comment: Thank you so much for your time JB. For future SO'ers, modified the function as shown at the end of the original question for database writes/reads using Timestamp. One last question, is there a long representation that makes sense to mysql timestamp? I am starting to loose faith in everything Date related